# Not able to refresh the partial view after a form submission from another partial view within it, using ajax in mvc razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my website I have a Facebook like chat page. I have implemented it with basic form submission method that will refresh the whole page when I post something. now I need to change it using ajax/jquery so that it should only refresh my partial views. I have written code for that and I changed my views by adding scripts.

My main Message view is like (sample):

```
 @model myModel
 <h2>
   Message Board<small class="on-right"/>
 </h2>

  // Text box for Adding Message(post)

  @Html.TextArea("Message", new { @placeholder = "Add a post", id = "Message" })      
 <input type="button" id="Post" value="Post"/>

 // partial view that displays all the messages along with its comments

 <div id="messagelist">
        @{
    Html.RenderPartial("_posts", Model.MessageList);
        }
    </div>
```

script for message page:

```
 $('#Post').click(function () {
        var url = "/MyController/Messages";
        var Message = $("#Message").val();
        $("#Message").val("");
        $.post(url, { Message: Message }, function (data) {
            $("#messagelist").html(data);
```

_post partial view:

```
 @model IEnumerable<Model.MessageList>

 //Foreach loop for displaying all the messages

 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
  <div >
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.UserName)
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.MessageText)

      //Foreach loop for displaying all the comments related to each message

       @foreach (var item1 in item.Comments)
           {
               @item1.UserName 
               @item1.MessageText
            }
   </div>

    //partial view for adding comments each for messages

     @Html.Partial("Comment", new ModelInstance { MessageId = item.MessageId })
    }
```

Comment partial view (I am using ajax form submit):

```
  @model ModelInstance

  //form for submitting a message instance with parent message id for adding a comment to the parent message

  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Comment", "MyController", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "messagelist" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.MessageId)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.CommentText, new { @placeholder = "leave a comment" })
 <button class="btn-file" type="submit"></button>
    </div>
}
```

Controller actions (sample):

```
  public ActionResult Messages(string Message)
    {
            ------------------------------
            create messag object
            ---------------------
            add to database
            -------------------
            fetch again for refreshing
            ------------------------
            return PartialView("_posts", refreshed list);
        }

    public ActionResult Comment(StudiMessageDetails Comment)
    {
        ------------------------------
            create messag object
            ---------------------
            add to database
            -------------------
            fetch again for refreshing

        return PartialView("_posts", msgDetails);
        }
```

Now the Posting message and posting comment is working perfectly. also when I post a message it only refreshes my main message view.

But **when I post a comment** it is giving me the refreshed **partial view only**. it is **not getting bound to the 'div id=messagelist'** and **not giving me the full page**. Can anybody tell where I am going wrong ? please help.

Comment: What you can do is, just add a another action method which return your partial view. Then call that action method using ajax call. So, your action will return the partial view and put it where you want in your page.

Comment: Your replacing all the contents of `<div id="messagelist">` with what you return in the `Messages` method, so is `refreshedlist` the correct data? But why would you do this - your updating almost all of the page (hardly worth using ajax to update the DOM). Why not just save the message, and the append the new message to the DOM (and save having to call the database again also)?

Comment: when somebody post a message or comment, that should come first in my view that's why I have to replace the whole messages. And this is happening perfectly with posting messages, the only problem is with adding comments. it only returns and displays my _post partial view.

Comment: _that should come first in my view_? Then update the DOM to make it the first item in the view! [jquery .perpend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) or [.before](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

Comment: And you haven't shown your script for posting a comment so how can we tell whats wrong with it.

Comment: I don't need a script. its an Ajax form submit. the problem is, I am not getting the main message view with a refreshed list after posting a comment. it only displays the refreshed list.

Comment: But your `Comment` method returns `return PartialView("_posts", msgDetails);`. Does the partial view returned by the model `msgDetails` render what you want (I doubt it). In any case you are going about this the wrong way. Partials are for reusable content. You should be using a `DisplayTemplate` or `EditorTemplate` (or just rendering the whole lot in the main view) because your rendering elements based on models. And why mix `Ajax.BeginForm` and jquery ajax? But I don't understand why you don't just save the message or comment, return JSON indicating success and just update the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Ajax.BeginForm()` is replacing the contents of `<div id="messagelist">` with the html from `return PartialView("_posts", msgDetails);`. I suspect the model `msgDetails` contains only the details of the comment's associated message so that's all your seeing.

I suggest to rethink your design, particularly the `Messages()` method, which after saving the message is calling the database to get all messages and returning the complete list - you already have all the data on the page so this seems completely unnecessary and just degrades performance. You could simplify it with the following

Partial view (note the partial is for one message, not a collection)

```
@model Model.Message
<div class="message">
  <div class=username">@Model.UserName</div>
  <div class=messagetext">@Model.MessageText</div>
  <div class="commentlist">
    @foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
    {
      <div class="comment">
        <div class="username">@comment.UserName<div>
        <div class="commenttext">@comment.MessageText<div>
      </div>
    }
  </div>
  <div>
    @Html.TextBox("CommentText", new { placeholder = "Leave a comment", id = "" }) // remove the id attribute so its not invalid html
    <button class="addcomment" data-id="@Model.MessageId">Add Comment</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Main View

```
@model myModel
...
@Html.TextArea("Message", new { placeholder = "Add a post" })  // no point adding the id - its already added for you    
<input type="button" id="Post" value="Post" />
<div id="messagelist">
  @foreach(var message in Model.MessageList)
  {
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_posts", message); }
  }
</div>
<div id="newmessage"> // style this as hidden
  @{ Html.RenderPartial("_posts"); }
</div>
```

Scripts

```
// Add a model or ViewBag property for the current user name
var userName = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.UserName))');

$('#Post').click(function () {
  var url = '@Url.Action("Message", "MyController")'; // dont hardcode!
  var message = $('#Message').val();
  $.post(url, { MessageText: message }, function (data) {
    if(data) {
      // clone the new message, update message id and add to DOM
      var html = $('#newmessage').clone();
      message.children('.username').text(userName);
      message.children('.messagetext').text(message);
      message.children('.newcomment').children('button').data('id', data);
      $('#messagelist').perpend(html); // add at top of list
      $('#Message').val(''); // clear message text
    } else {
      // something went wrong
    }
  });
});

$('.addcomment').click(function() {
  var url = '@Url.Action("Comment", "MyController")';
  var comment = $(this).prev('input');
  var messageID = $(this).data('id');
  var list = $(this).closest('.message').children('.commentlist');
  $.post(url, { MessageID: messageID, CommentText comment.val() }, function (data) {
    if (data) {
      // add message
      var html = $('<div><div>').addClass('comment');
      html.append($('<div><div>').addClass('username').text(userName));
      html.append($('<div><div>').addClass('commenttext').text(commentText));
      list.append(html); // add to end of existing comments
      comment.val(''); // clear existing text
    } else {
      // something went wrong
    }
  });
});
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Message(string MessageText)
{
  // create new message object and save to database
  int ID = // the ID of the new message
  return Json(ID); // if exception, then return null;
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Comment(int MessageID, string CommentText)
{
  // create new comment object and save to database
  return Json(true); // if exception, then return null;
}
```

Comment: Sir, first of all thank you for taking effort to help me. the http post is working and it is passing the correct values to the controller. but <div id="newmessage"> // style this as hidden
  @{ Html.RenderPartial("_posts"); }
</div> this line is giving me exception because "_post" partial view needs a object of type message to be passed, it is giving me object null exception.

Comment: Also for the first message in the list, when I am adding a comment to it, it adds multiple times.

Comment: Check my answer again. Its `@{ Html.RenderPartial("_posts", message); }`. Let me check the other issue shortly

Comment: OK, I see it now, it needs to be `@{ Html.RenderPartial("_posts", new Message()); }`, but you also need to make sure that in the constructor for `Message` you initialize the Comments - `Comments = new List<Comments>();` (I don't know what your models are so I needed to make a few guesses)

Comment: Can't see why it would add multiple comments? Put breakpoints on the scripts and step through the code with the debugger to check whats happening.

Comment: ok, I checked those and now its building and running, multiple adding of comments is also gone. but its not giving me the refreshed page after adding a message or comments. its not prepending or appending data. but when I am refreshing the page manually, it comes.

Comment: In the `$('#Post').click(..`, try `$('#messagelist').perpend(html.html());`, and for the second one try `list.append(html.html());`

Comment: Can you post your models. That's the only way I can actually test this.